# How to parse requests.session cookie attributes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, cookiejar

I'm writing a python 3 script to check particular attributes of a cookie on a site I'm working on. I currently authenticate to the site with `requests.session`:

```
SiteLogin = 'https://mytestsite.com/login'
payload = {'username': USER, 'password': PASSWORD}
s = requests.session()
s.post(SiteLogin, data=payload)
s.cookies
```

Now, the cookies have a number of attributes *including name, domain, expiration, etc*. I wasn't able to find a method to actually expose all of the attributes as a dictionary for a given cookie so that I could parse out the expected values.

Is there a method I missed?

**EDIT**

Updated to clarify what I'm seeing:

```
>>> s.cookies
<RequestsCookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='COOKIE_NAME', value='COOKIE_VALUE', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='DOMAIN, domain_specified=False, domain_initial_dot=False, path='PATH', path_specified=True, secure=True, expires=None, discard=True, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={'HttpOnly': None}, rfc2109=False)]>
```

```
>>> print(s.cookies)
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie 'COOKIE_NAME'='COOKIE_VALUE' for DOMAIN+PATH>]>
```

```
>>> print(s.cookies.get_dict())
{'COOKIE_NAME': 'COOKIE_VALUE'}
```

So, lets say I wanted to get the 'expires' value for each cookie (notice above, this is available by running s.cookies). How can I access just the expiry value? If there are many cookies on my system, is it possible to loop through them all, and check the expiry on each?

Something like:

```
>>> s.cookies['expires']
None
```

Comment: So do you want to modify the cookies in the session or just print them?

Comment: Print them is fine. Couldn't find a good way to access them as individual attributes.

Comment: Great, I've just submitted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, found a solution based on Fozoro's answer. The cookie object within the cookiejar contains the member attributes I was interested in.

```
payload = {'username': USER, 'password': PASSWORD}
s = requests.session()
s.post(SiteLogin, data=payload)
for cookie in list(s.cookies):
    print(cookie.expires)
```

Answer (score 1):

So in order to just print the cookies you can try implement the following code:

```
payload = {'username': USER, 'password': PASSWORD}
s = requests.session()
s.post(SiteLogin, data=payload)
list(s.cookies)
```

hope this helps

Comment: So, when I run s.cookies.get_dict() all I get is: {'CookieName':'CookieValue'}
I don't get Domain, path, etc. (which are displayed by s.cookies). Is there a way for me to get the 'domain' attribute alone, or any other attribute displayed by s.cookies?

Comment: So if when you do `print(s.cookies)` you are getting Domain and Path but when you doing `print(s.cookies.get_dict())` you only get `{'CookieName':'CookieValue'}`?

Comment: So, I tried a few things:
>>> s.cookies
# Returns all attributes, including domain, expires, path, etc.
>>> print(s.cookies)
# Returns 'CookieName'='CookieValue' for 'Domain''
>>> print(s.cookies.get_dict())
# Returns {'CookieName':'CookieValue'}

I want to get at any of the individual attributes returned by s.cookie per cookie. For instance, get all of the 'expires' attributes for each cookie. I was hoping there was a way to loop through a dictionary per cookie, and evaluating the attributes.

Comment: Could you possibly edit your question add your current output and the desired one, That would help a lot!

Comment: Edited. Thanks for the assistance Fozoro!

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my code though I'm still not 100% sure if it's what you want :)

Comment: Added one more edit above, showing what my ideal outcome would be.

Comment: Great! could you also provide `SiteLogin` (the URL)?

Comment: Added test url.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I'd suggest you use the following syntax as suggested in the [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/requests/cookies/):

```
s.cookies.get('expires')
```